# CSS: Floating image and text to left in list item, with no text wrap beneath image

Tags: html, css

Scenario:

I have a box (300px wide by 300px tall.) I have an unordered list within this box, which has four list items. Each item consists of a thumnail image (32X32), a link link directly to the right of the thumbnail and then a string of text that's on the next line beneath the link.

Notes:

1. I want the top of the link to be aligned with the top of the image.
2. The string of text (which is a publication date) needs to be on it's own line, below the link (but not wrapping beneath the image.)

Current implementation:

```
<ul>
<li><img class="thumb" src="baby.jpg"><a href="http://example.com" class="post-link">Post link title</a><br/>Date goes here</li>
<li>And again...</li>
<li>And again...</li>
<li>And again.</li>
</ul>
```

And for my CSS:

```
img .thumb {
float: left;
 width: 32px;
 height: 32px;
display: inline;
 }

a .post-link {
 float: left;
 display: inline;
 }
```

Currently, my image is on its own line, and then the text is beneath it. I'm tired and cranky -- and this is only one of many bugs. Help this poor, tired guy, will you?

Answer (score 1):

It should be `img.thumb` - no space; or just plain `.thumb` if you are only using it for the `img` tags, same goes for the `a.post-link`.

`img.thumb` means you are targeting an `img` element that has the class `.thumb`.

`img .thumb` means you are targeting elements with the `.thumb` class that have parents that are `img` elements.

[CSS selectors for reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the picture and text within a `div`

```
<ul>
<li><div><div><img class="thumb" src="baby.jpg"></div><a href="http://example.com" class="post-link">Post link title</a><br/>Date goes here</div></li>
<li>And again...</li>
<li>And again...</li>
<li>And again.</li>
</ul>

.thumb {
float: left;
 width: 32px;
 height: 32px;
display: inline;
 }

.post-link {
 float: left;
 display: inline;
 }
```

Fiddle (I used a black div to represent a picture, it should all work the same) : [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ff7q7pax/4/)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want like this.

```
<ul>
    <li><div style="float:left;"><img class="thumb" src="baby.jpg"></div><a href="http://example.com" class="post-link">Post link title</a><br/>Date goes here</li>
<li>And again...</li>
<li>And again...</li>
<li>And again.</li>
</ul>
```

The CSS

```
img.thumb {
 width: 32px;
 height: 32px;
display: inline;
 }

a .post-link {
 display: inline;
 }
```

Just wrap div inside the image with float inside. Others will adjust it itself